# Check if status is either of 2 values and then check if equal to another

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a table where an application has multiple records as the status can change. For example it can be "new", "invited", " completed", "signedup".

First I want to check if the  ID has a row where status code is either 1 ( "new") OR 2("signed up") AND then check if the ID has a row where status code is 5 ("signedup").

In the sample data below I have shown that ID's 1 and 4 match the criteria given above.

[image]

I have tried the following code ( variables do not match sample code ) but it does not work.

```
  summarize 1 = var inv_new =  CALCULATETABLE('Application Progress Links','Application Progress Links'[Status (Code)] IN {1,2})
                RETURN  COUNTROWS(FILTER(CALCULATETABLE('Application Progress Links','Application Progress Links'[Status (Code)] = 5), 'Application Progress Links'[ApplicationId]IN inv_new)
              )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were almost there... `inv_new` has to be a single column table for the `IN` to work for the IDs.

```
Measure = 
  var inv_new = CALCULATETABLE(
    VALUES('Application Progress Links'[ApplicationId]),
    'Application Progress Links'[Status (Code)] IN {1, 2}
  )
  RETURN CALCULATE(
    DISTINCTCOUNT('Application Progress Links'[ApplicationId]),
    'Application Progress Links'[ApplicationId] in inv_new &&
    'Application Progress Links'[Status (Code)] = 5
  )
```

Comment: Thank you very much. One more question please. I should of used summarize as i need to get the earliest timestamp for each applciation ID. So i changed your code to use summarize but it gives the following error " The number of arguements is invalid. Function CONTAINSROW must hav a value for each column in the table expression.

Comment: summarize function  - 
var inv_new = SUMMARIZE('Application Progress Links','Application Progress Links'[ApplicationId] , "Status count", COUNTROWS(FILTER('Application Progress Links','Application Progress Links'[Status (Code)]=2  ||  'Application Progress Links'[Status (Code)]=1 )),"earliest date",CALCULATE(MIN('Application Progress Links'[DW_CreationDateTime])))

Comment: What are you trying to do? Create a calculated table or something other calculation? Share a bit more info

Comment: First i want to get learners with status code 1 or 2 and their earliest date(each record has a timestamp)  and then check if those records also have a record where status code is 5. Thanks for your help so far :)